# Embedding Python in C++: how to parse a list returned from Python function?

Tags: python, c++

My code looks something like this:

```cpp
  PyObject *pArguments, *pArgumentValue;

  pArgumentValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunction, pArguments);
  Py_DECREF(pArguments);


  if (pArgumentValue != NULL) {
    #?????????????????
  } else {

    PyErr_Print();
  }
```

I would like to parse the return value of the python method, which returns a list of lists of floating point values. It's my first time working with python embeds in cpp, so I would appreciate any help and examples!
The result of this parsing can be a list or a vector in cpp, it doesn't matter that much, as long as this data is usable.

Comment: Have you tried the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html), particularly the sections on the sequence protocol and iterator protocol? How about the corresponding [guide](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html)?

Comment: It seems that I have not - but I can see that I can work with this. Iterate over the sequence and add data to whatever container I see fit. Thanks, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PySequence was the answer!

```cpp
  PyObject *pArguments, *pArgumentValue;
  pArguments=nullptr;

  pArgumentValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunction, pArguments);


  if (pArgumentValue != NULL) {
    cout << "result:" << PySequence_Check(pArgumentValue);
    for (int i = 0; i < PySequence_Size(pArgumentValue); i++) {
      if (PySequence_GetItem(pArgumentValue, i) != NULL) {
        for (int j = 0;
             j < PySequence_Size(PySequence_GetItem(pArgumentValue, i)); j++) {
          cout << "Field: " << i << "Measurement: " << j << " :"
                   << PyLong_AsLong(PySequence_GetItem(
                          PySequence_GetItem(pArgumentValue, i), j));
        }
      }
    }
```